# Приветствую! Я хотел бы узнать, как сделать когда не верно отправляешь команду бота

Tags: discord, discord.py

**Например когда пишешь команду *!бан* без упоминания человека, то бот будет писать чтобы мы упоминули человека которого хотим забанить, вот сам код бана**

```py
#Команда для бана участника сервера
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = 0xEC2C2D,
    title="Ban",
    description=f"Ban user { member.mention }"
    )
    embed.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    embed.set_author( name = bot.user.name, icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url )
    await member.ban()
    await ctx.send( embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее, можно сделать что-то подобное:

```
if not member in msg:
   await ctx.send('укажите кого хотите забанить')
```

Ну или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Это легко сделать. Нужно лишь отметить, что `member: discord.Member` является `None`, а так-же в коде добавить строку: `if member == None`.

```
@bot.command()
async def testban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.channel.send("Хей, братан! Ты случаем не забыл.. Отметить участника, которого хочешь забанить?")
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = 0xEC2C2D,
    title="Ban",
    description=f"Ban user { member.mention }"
    )
    embed.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    embed.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )
    await member.ban()
    await ctx.send( embed = embed)
```

По запросу автора данного вопроса я делаю версию с Embed:

````
@bot.command()
async def testban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f'Уважаемый администратор {ctx.author}!', description='Пожалуйста, отметьте пользователя, которого вы хотите забанить!',color=0xe74c3c))
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = 0xEC2C2D,
    title="Ban",
    description=f"Ban user { member.mention }"
    )
    embed.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    embed.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )
    await member.ban()
    await ctx.send( embed = embed)
    ```
````

Comment: Если я был полезен, пожалйста, оставьте какой нибудь комментарий! Мне будет приятно :)

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ли как-то сделать это в ембеде?

Comment: Пару секунд, @halflite

Comment: Ох, моя беда! Обновляю ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, дружище! Ты мне очень помог :3

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!